# Why doesn't a Dictionary access nonexistent keys like a Hashtable does?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable

If I'm using a `Hashtable`, I can write code like this:

```
object item = hashtable[key] ?? default_value;
```

That works whether or not `key` appears in the `Hashtable`.

I can't do that with a `Dictionary<TKey. TValue>`.  If the key's not present in the dictionary, that will throw a `KeyNotFoundException`.  So I have to write code like this:

```
MyClass item;
if (!(dict.TryGetValue(key, out item))
{
   item = default_value;
}
```

I'm wondering why this is.  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is just a wrapper around `Hashtable`.  Why has this restriction been added to it?

**Edit:**

For another perspective on PopCatalin's answer (see below), the code I'd written above won't work if the dictionary's values are of a value type.  If I'm using a `Dictionary<int, int>`, then the code I would *like* to use looks like this:

```
int i = dict[key] ?? default_value;
```

And that won't compile, because `dict[key]` isn't a nullable or reference type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between a `Dictionary<T>` and a `Hashtable` is that a `Dictionary<T>` is a generic type that can specialize to store value types along reference types.

The hashtable can only store reference types (a `Object` passed by reference) and only value types that are boxed (also passed by reference).

When a dictionary is specialized with value types, it must return those values 'by value' not by reference.So, therefore, a `Dictionary<T>` can't return null, as null is **not a valid value** for value types.

Answer (score 4):

There is one misconception in your post.  Dictionary is not a wrapper around Hashtable.  It's a completely different implementation.

The reason why this change was made is mainly justified by one assertion: Null is a valid value for a hashtable.  Without this change it's not possible to distinguish between a non-exsistent key and a value key with a null value using the [] method of access.  Dictionary clears this up.

Comment: +1 because I've never looked in a dictionary and not said "WTF?" when I didn't find the word I was looking for.

Comment: JaredPar, if I examine System.Collections.DictionaryBase in Reflector, I see that it's using a Hashtable as its underlying data structure.  Am I looking at the wrong thing?

Comment: I'll answer my own question:  Dictionary<TKey, TValue> doesn't derive from DictionaryBase.  I don't know why I was so sure it did, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary.ContainsKey is probably better for you than TryGetValue.

But as to why, no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an extension for this.

```
public static class DictionaryExtension
{
    public static TValue GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> items, string key)
    {
        if (items != null && items.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return items[key];
        }

        return default(TValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look to the code using Reflector you'll see that Dictionary tries to find the key and *explicitly* raises an exception if it doesn't find the key.

```
public TValue get_Item(TKey key)
{
    int index = this.FindEntry(key);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return this.entries[index].value;
    }
    ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
    return default(TValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this restriction is one of the functional reasons for the creation of the wrapper in the first place.